# How to scale text within a fixed rectangle with itext7?

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core, itext7

I'm trying to make a pdf document with itext7 in c# which should have fixed rectangles containing varying text that should scale within the boundaries of the (invisible) rectangles.

I have tried to find if there's automatic scaling, but so far only found auto-scaling for formfields. Since the pdf will be used for plotting text, formfields are of no use.

Code below is a snippet placing a 'box' with fixed dimensions, where all the text should be shown scaled (on one line)

```
float fontSize = 22f;

Text lineTxt = new Text("A VERY LONG TEXT SHOULD BE SCALED").SetFont(lineFont).SetFontSize(fontSize);

iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle lineTxtRect = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(100, posHeight - 200, (float)plotline.producttype_plotmaxwidthpts, (float)plotline.producttype_plotmaxheightpts);

Div lineDiv = new Div();
lineDiv.SetMaxHeight((float)plotline.producttype_plotmaxheightpts);
lineDiv.SetWidth((float)plotline.producttype_plotmaxwidthpts);
lineDiv.SetHeight((float)plotline.producttype_plotmaxheightpts);
lineDiv.SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
lineDiv.SetBorder(new DashedBorder(1));

Paragraph linePara = new Paragraph().Add(lineTxt).
        SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER).
        SetBorder(new DottedBorder(1)).
        SetMultipliedLeading(0.7f).
        SetMaxHeight((float)plotline.producttype_plotmaxheightpts).
        SetHeight((float)plotline.producttype_plotmaxheightpts);

lineDiv.Add(linePara);

new Canvas(PageCanvas, pdf, lineTxtRect).Add(lineDiv).SetBorder(new SolidBorder(1f));
```

Comment: Your code samples contains references to variables like `plotline` and `posHeight` which are absolutely unclear. Please make sure to include a short code sample that reproduces the problem without additional guess work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout module of iText 7 allows you to simulate rendering of an element (by creating the renderer tree from the element and then using `Layout` method) and check whether it fits the given area (by checking `LayoutResult` object). Thus what you can do is check whether the text fits into your fixed rectangle with the given font size. Then you can just do a binary search on the font size.

Here is a sample code:

```cs
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));

Text lineTxt = new Text("A VERY LONG TEXT SHOULD BE SCALED");

iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle lineTxtRect = 
    new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(100,200,100,100);

Div lineDiv = new Div();
lineDiv.SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
lineDiv.SetBorder(new DashedBorder(1));

Paragraph linePara = 
  new Paragraph()
    .Add(lineTxt)
    .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .SetBorder(new DottedBorder(1))
    .SetMultipliedLeading(0.7f);
lineDiv.Add(linePara);

// 1 is the font size that is definitely small enough to draw all the text
float fontSizeL = 1;

// 20 is the maximum value of the font size you want to use
float fontSizeR = 20;

Canvas canvas = 
    new Canvas(
        new PdfCanvas(pdfDocument.AddNewPage()), 
        pdfDocument,
         lineTxtRect);

// Binary search on the font size
while (Math.Abs(fontSizeL - fontSizeR) > 1e-1) {

    float curFontSize = (fontSizeL + fontSizeR) / 2;
    lineDiv.SetFontSize(curFontSize);

    // It is important to set parent for the current element renderer
    // to a root renderer.
    IRenderer renderer = 
        lineDiv.CreateRendererSubTree()
            .SetParent(canvas.GetRenderer());

    LayoutContext context = 
        new LayoutContext(
            new LayoutArea(1, lineTxtRect));

    if (renderer.Layout(context).GetStatus() == LayoutResult.FULL) {
        // we can fit all the text with curFontSize
        fontSizeL = curFontSize;
    } else {
        fontSizeR = curFontSize;
    }
}

// Use the biggest font size that is still small enough to fit all the
// text.
lineDiv.SetFontSize(fontSizeL);
canvas.Add(lineDiv);

pdfDocument.Close();
```

Comment: I had to remove the Text element and add text directly into the Paragraph object, but then it works as intended. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: Although related, i came across another issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971693/text-scaling-problem-with-itext7-hidden-margins)